# Cloning tuples in a list by the length of each tuple in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples

I have the following list of tuples:

```
indices = [(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

I am running the following and getting:

```
indices2 = []
for j in range(len(indices)):
    indices2.append(indices[j] * len(indices[j]))
indices2
```

Which gives:

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2, 1, 2), (1, 3, 1, 3), (2, 3, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)]
```

However, I want to obtain:

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3),
(1, 2, 3)]
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a list of nested lists and then flatten it out after the for loop:

```
import itertools

indices = [(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]

indices2 = []
for j in range(len(indices)):
    indices2.append([indices[j]]*len(indices[j]))

chain = itertools.chain(*indices2)
indices2 = list(chain)
print indices2
```

`[indices[j]]*len(indices[j])` creates lists each with `len(indices[j])` amount of `indices[j]` tuples. The resulting nested list `indices2` is then flatten into a single, not-nested list using `itertools.chain`.

Another approach would be a nested `for` loop:

```
indices2 = []
for j in range(len(indices)):
    for jln in range(len(indices[j])):
        indices2.append(indices[j])
```

Here the loop simply appends tuples `len(indices[j])` time.

The first was may be more pythonic and it looks nicer, the second is simpler. The first may also have more overhead which should be verified if the problem needs performance upgrades.

Comment: `list(chain(*[(t,) * len(t) for t in indices]))` in one line.

Comment: @salparadise Thank you, I like the one line solutions best :) I'll add it with an acknowledgement if you don't want to post an answer.

Comment: Trying to fit everything into a oneliner can be harmful, I suggest you first make it correct and if it can be more expressive ,then let that be a secondary goal. Also, I took the logic your answer :), if you want upvote another one of my answers you like :)

Comment: @salparadise Gladly :) You definitely extended my logic, I learned a few more tricks with this one. Definitely agree that one should be careful with oneliners (this one looks good though :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
indices = [(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
indices2=[]
for j in indices:
    indices2.append([j]*len(j))
print indices2
```

the problem with ur code is  when the item being repeated is a list. The list will not be cloned: all the elements will refer to the same list!
example:

```
>>> a=[5,2,7]
>>> a*3
[5, 2, 7, 5, 2, 7, 5, 2, 7]
>>> [a]*3
[[5, 2, 7], [5, 2, 7], [5, 2, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, you just have to use `extend` if you want to append multiple items and wrap it in some container before multiplying it:

```
>>> indices2 = []
>>> for j in range(len(indices)):
...     indices2.extend([indices[j]] * len(indices[j]))
>>> indices2
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

However you could even shorten it by using a comprehension:

```
>>> [item for item in indices for _ in range(len(item))]
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

As to why your approach didn't work, when you multiply a `tuple` you create a new tuple containing repeats of the original:

```
>>> (1, 2) * 2
(1, 2, 1, 2)
```

That's not what you want, however if you wrap it in a `list` and then multiply it, you repeat the tuple multiple times as different tuples:

```
>>> [(1, 2)] * 2
[(1, 2), (1, 2)]
```

And by using `extend` instead of `append` you just insert the elements of the "list", so it should be working as expected.

However the multiplication doesn't really copy, it just inserts the same reference multiple times. You're on the safe side by using a comprehension to repeat it:

```
>>> [(1, 2) for _ in range(2)]
[(1, 2), (1, 2)]
```

The nested comprehension is a bit more complicated but it just replaces the outer loop and the implicit loop inside `extend` with comprehensions. It's essentially equivalent to:

```
indices2 = []
for item in indices:
    for _ in range(len(item)):  # equivalent to the implicit loop of "extend"
        indices2.append(item)
```